# Converting a text file of strings (not in exact dict format) to a dict with tuple keys and float values?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a text file ("output.txt") that's contents are in a format as follows:

```
(ABC, DEF): 12.5
(DEF, FEG): 13.5
(RED, FEG): 14.5
```

I want to convert it to a dict, with keys being a tuple consisting of two strings, and the values being floats:

```
{('ABC','DEF'): 12.5, ('DEF','FEG'): 13.5, ('RED','FEG'): 14.5}
```

I tried reading in the file, with each line being a string. Then I tried using replace to get each line to this format:

```
{('ABC', 'DEF'): '12.5'}
```

I thought then I could get it into a format such that I could use ast.literal_eval(), but this doesn't quite work because when constructing a list into this format, you get extra quotation marks, etc. Is there a better approach than what I'm trying?

Comment: consider using the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) module. Does all the job for you, and you can define the separator to be either `:`, or `=`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
with open('output.txt') as f: 
    print({tuple(k.strip('()').split(', ')): float(v.strip())
            for line in f for k, _, v in [line.partition(':')]})
```

here inside the dict comprehension, we're iterating over the lines, partitioning them on `:` to get key-value pairs, and finally converting them in desired form for keys and values.

**Example:**

```
In [29]: cat output.txt                                                                                                                                                                                     
(ABC, DEF): 12.5
(DEF, FEG): 13.5
(RED, FEG): 14.5

In [30]: with open('output.txt') as f: 
    ...:     print({tuple(k.strip('()').split(', ')): float(v.strip()) for line in f for k, _, v in [line.partition(':')]}) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
{('ABC', 'DEF'): 12.5, ('DEF', 'FEG'): 13.5, ('RED', 'FEG'): 14.5}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you think you could walk me through the list comprehension here? Does "k, _, v" include a placeholder given that there are two elements before the :? Specifically, is there any need for the "_", or can you just do k,v?

Comment: @J.P. That's a dict comprehension. We're putting the output from `str.partition` in a list so that we can refer it by unpacking without using an intermediate variable. You should read about `str.partition`.

Comment: That makes sense, but is the underscore here a placeholder (since str.partition returns a tuple and a value)? Does that underscore represent the separator parameter, which is blank?

Comment: @J.P. `_` is a placeholder for the separator; `str.partition(':')` returns a tuple of three elements: `(<whatever_before_:>, ':', <whatever_after_:>)`.

Comment: Makes sense - sorry, one last thing, how would one express this if not doing list comprehension (i.e. breaking it down into loops)? I understand looping over for line in f, then doing for k, underscore, v in line.partition, would you then update results to a dict?

Comment: @J.P. I'm doing a dict comprehension, not a list comprehension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196838/discussion-between-j-p-and-heemayl).